# Select maximum value from all previous rows (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, max, window-functions

I have a table that looks as follows:

```
personid  opendate  fraud
       1  20190105      0
       1  20190715      1
       1  20191011      0
       5  20181205      0
       5  20190105      0
       5  20190705      1
```

I want to get the maximum value of `fraud` **up until each date** grouped by `personid`. That is, I want to get the following table:

```
personid  opendate  fraud  ever_fraud
       1  20190105      0           0  <-  no preceding frauds yet
       1  20190715      1           1  <-  fraud committed
       1  20191011      0           1  <-  fraud committed in previous credit
       5  20181205      0           0
       5  20190105      0           0
       5  20190705      1           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select 
    t.*,
    max(fraud) over(partition by personid order by opendate) ever_fraud
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5da25314300c7a0b9b9447956557d087)**:

```
PERSONID | OPENDATE | FRAUD | EVER_FRAUD
-------: | -------: | ----: | ---------:
       1 | 20190105 |     0 |          0
       1 | 20190715 |     1 |          1
       1 | 20191011 |     0 |          1
       5 | 20181205 |     0 |          0
       5 | 20190105 |     0 |          0
       5 | 20190705 |     1 |          1
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like suggesting `lag()` analytic function :

```
with t2 as
(
select t.*,
       lag(fraud,1,0) over (partition by personid order by opendate) as ever_fraud0
  from t
)
select personid, opendate, fraud,
       case when fraud = 1 then fraud else ever_fraud0 end as ever_fraud
  from t2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=439b96cb0a3d32fe1114b0520aa2514d)</kbd>